# How to Select records coming in Next 12 Hours?

Tags: mysql, date, select, time

I am storing some records in a table named bookings_mst. I am storing booking date & booking time separately into fields as booking_date & booking_time. Now I want to select records that has the time coming in Next 12 Hours. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant -

```
SELECT * FROM bookings_mst
WHERE
 ADDTIME(booking_date, booking_time) BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR;
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't work when 2 dates are involved. E.g. current date is 12 & time is 10pm & booking date is 13 & time is 3AM. It won't show up.

Comment: Please show your dataset - some INSERT statements and desired result.

Comment: Hi Devart, there was some miss-understanding. Later on I found that date was store with wrong values. Your query is perfected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_field, INTERVAL time_field HOUR_SECOND) BETWEEN
    NOW() AND 
    DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the date and time in a single datetime field, then the query becomes fairly easy. Something like this should suffice

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where booking_datetime between utc_timestamp() 
                           and utc_timestamp() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR;
```